# Can't update siteurl and home for my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have recently enabled https on my blog. Now, I can't update its WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL). I have tried all three options I found so far

Option 1: Change from UI - I can't change from UI because that option is grayed out

Option 2: Update functions.php - I have updated the functions.php and added the following at the end

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://example.net' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://example.net' );
```

Option 3: Updated the database tables directly

```
wp option update home 'https://example.net'
wp option update siteurl 'https://example.net'
```

To confirm I did this

```
wp option list  --search=home
wp option list --search=siteurl
```

And I get https://example.net

So even after trying all the three options when I go to my site settings I see http://example.net as WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)

Comment: You installed SSL thats why you are adding an `s` to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are greyed put in the admin Settings page, then you most likely have `WP_HOME` and  `WP_SITEURL` set in your `wp-config.php` file as this will override whatever was set in the WP Settings (which is the same as what’s in the database).

Check your wp-config for something like this:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.net');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.net’);
```

You can change it to https in these lines or you could delete these lines and let the settings in the database take effect instead.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have fixed it. It had define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/'); and 
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/'); . I updated it to https

Comment: Glad it fixed it for you. These settings will override the database and admin settings (which are one and the same) so you can either change them here or delete them to let the database settings take effect.